# VBA based file dialog (with scenario based switch)

Tags: vba, excel

The code imports 3 types of files, depending on the button selected. Something I might add is a check that the user has selected the right file - not too sure how I could do this.

I've been working on this code for about 2 weeks, and I've got it to a point where I'm happy. It's functional, copies data correctly, and allows my dashboard to operate so much quicker than before with manual updating.

I would like a critical review of my code for shortfalls and bad practices that I can cut out of any future programs, and any improvements I can make that help efficiency.

```
Sub GetFile(Fileoption As Integer)

Dim directory As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
  Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
  Dim filetype As Integer
  Dim fileurl As String
  Dim fdmulti As Boolean
  Dim fdButton As String
  Dim fdTitle As String
  Dim allList As Workbook
  Dim allName As String
  Dim importfile As Workbook
  Dim fileName As String
  Dim workrng As Range
  Dim myRange As Range
  Dim numRows As Integer
  Dim numCols As Integer
  Dim pcbdata As String 'Name of worksheet in PCB that contains project data
  Dim urlPCB As String
  Dim urlESO As String
  Dim urlGate As String
  Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant


   'if error

'Set values for file dialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fdmulti = False
fdButton = "Import"
fdTitle = ""

> pcbdata = "name of sheet in workbook that contains data" ' NOTE - if name of sheet changes import will fail

'Set values for locations of files

urlPCB = "sharepoint file location url"
urlESO = "sharepoint file location url"
urlGate = "sharepoint file location url"
'File locations for PCB/ESO/GateReview

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Select Case Fileoption 'Initialises FileDialog to open file for each specific case PCB/ESO/GateReview
    Case 1
      fileurl = urlPCB
      fdTitle = "Select PCB File"
    Case 2
      fileurl = urlESO
      fdTitle = "Select ESO File"
    Case 3
      fileurl = urlGate
      fdTitle = "Select Gate Review File"
   End Select

Set allList = ActiveWorkbook
allName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    With fd ' uses the FileDialog box to find and open the file
        .Title = fdTitle
        .AllowMultiSelect = fdmulti
        .InitialFileName = fileurl
        .ButtonName = fdButton
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.csv ; *.xlsm ; *.xlsx", 1

        If .Show = True Then 'initiates FileDialog Box
        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems 'Opens selected file from Local/Ensemble directory
            Workbooks.Open (vrtSelectedItem)
        Next
        End If

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then 'if user selects Cancel
        MsgBox "File selection cancelled"
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Saves the opened file's name for later reference
    Set importfile = ActiveWorkbook 'Saves Wookbook object for potential use


  'Turns off automatic updates for formulas to make the process faster
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Select Case Fileoption ' copies relevant data depending on type of file opened
   Case 1
    Windows(allName).Activate ' Clears PCB data sheet in Comparison workbook
    Sheets("PCB Data").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    selectBlock().ClearContents
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Windows(fileName).Activate ' Copy and pastes data from PCB All projects list
    Sheets(pcbdata).Activate
    selectBlock().Copy

    Windows(allName).Activate
    Sheets("PCB Data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Windows(fileName).Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox "PCB projects Imported"
   Case 2
   Windows(allName).Activate ' Clears ESO data sheet in Comparison workbook
    Sheets("ESO Data").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    selectBlock().Clear
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

   Windows(fileName).Activate
     Dim ws As Worksheet ' Runs through all worksheets

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'repeat copy paste for each sheet in the ESO file
        Windows(fileName).Activate
        ws.Activate
        selectBlock().Copy

        Windows(allName).Activate
        Sheets("ESO Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Windows(fileName).Close savechanges:=False

     MsgBox "ESO data Imported"
   Case 3
    Windows(allName).Activate ' Clears Gate Review data sheet in Comparison workbook
    Sheets("Gate Review").Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    selectBlock().Clear
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Windows(fileName).Activate ' Copy and pastes data from Gate Review file
    selectBlock().Copy

    Windows(allName).Activate
    Sheets("Gate Review").Range("A2").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    Windows(fileName).Activate
    Sheets("Confirmed Closed Projects ").Activate
    selectBlock().Copy

    Windows(allName).Activate
    Sheets("Gate Review").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    Windows(fileName).Close savechanges:=False

    MsgBox "Gate review Imported"
   End Select

    Sheets("Tools").Activate
    Cells(2, 1).Select

    'Turns back on automaic updates for formulas
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  Exit Sub

Errorhandler: ' catches the error when no file is selected or any other error
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "File selection cancelled"
    Else
    MsgBox Err.Description
    End If

End Sub
```

Supporting Code Subs and Functions

```
Function PCB(num As Integer) As Integer ' Handles which type of file is wanted
GetFile (num)

End Function

Sub ButtonPCB()
' PCB button
PCB (1)
End Sub

Sub ButtonESO()
' ESO button
PCB (2)
End Sub

Sub GateReview()
PCB (3) ' Gate Review button
End Sub

Function selectBlock() As Range

Dim row As Long: row = numRows() 'Finds last populated row
Dim col As Long: col = numCols() 'Finds last populated column

Set selectBlock = Range("A2:" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Address(False, False))
'sets this area starting from cell A2 as the Range

End Function

Function numCols() As Long

    'Dim myRange As Range
    'Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("1:1") 'Checks first row to see how many populated columns there are
    numCols = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function

Function numRows() As Long
    'Dim myRange As Range
    'Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A") 'Checks first columns to see how many populated rows there are
    numRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Toby for the description improvement - I've never been the best at writing

Comment: This is good work +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option Explicit

You've declared all your variable, yay! But you should put `Option Explicit` at the top in case you forget. Always turn on `Option Explicit`. You can have it automatically by going to Tools -> Options in the VBE and checking the **Require Variable Declaration** option. This way if you have any variables not defined, the compiler will let you know.

I'm going to assume this line is just a typo, there's no reason for the ">" and it breaks the procedure

```
> pcbdata = "name of sheet in workbook that contains data" ' NOTE - if name of sheet changes import will fail
```

---

#### Flow

So a user clicks one of three buttons and that sends an argument to your "GetFile". This sends an argument to `Function PCB` which then calls `GetFile` with an argument. But your PCB function doesn't return anything anywhere, it's an extra step. Just eliminate it entirely.

Once that argument goes to `GetFile` you set three different URLs to strings and then `Select Case` on them -

> ```
> urlPCB = "sharepoint file location url"
> urlESO = "sharepoint file location url"
> urlGate = "sharepoint file location url"
> Select Case Fileoption 'Initialises FileDialog to open file for each specific case PCB/ESO/GateReview
>     Case 1
>       fileurl = urlPCB
>       fdTitle = "Select PCB File"
>     Case 2
>       fileurl = urlESO
>       fdTitle = "Select ESO File"
>     Case 3
>       fileurl = urlGate
>       fdTitle = "Select Gate Review File"
>    End Select
> ```

Usually I'd say make the URLs constants, but in this case just place them directly in the `Select Case` because you aren't using them again.

Then you start the file dialog, but I'm not sure why you have the

> ```
> If .Show = True Then
> ```

*oh wait yes I do, it's the example everywhere*

Just `.Show` it. As a side note, when you `if` test a boolean, you don't need to put `= True` because it *is* true. `If .Show Then`. So if you get rid of that, your `For Each vrtSelectItem` will run, but not cause any errors because it's running over nothing. Your next `If` will catch that error. But, if a user hits `Cancel` they don't need to be told, IMHO. So just catch the error explicitly -

```
.Show 
If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems 
   Workbooks.Open (vrtSelectedItem)
Next
```

Or if you want

```
If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
```

Good. But now you are getting the `ActiveWorkbook.Name` of whatever was opened last. It would be better to get those earlier with a `Workbooks` collection:

```
For i = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    myWorkbooks.Add .SelectedItems(i)
Next
```

***But***, you don't allow multiselect:

> ```
> fdmulti = False
>  With fd 
>     .Title = fdTitle
>     .AllowMultiSelect = fdmulti
> ```

So you don't need a collection, you just need a single workbook

```
Dim targetWorkbook as Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
```

Now you have that workbook in a variable. Also, now you don't need to do all this `.Activate` - you know what sheet and how to get the range. And, correct me if I'm wrong, right now you're taking all the sheets. So

```
If Not .Show Then Exit Sub
   Set targetWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1))
   For i = 1 To targetWorkBook.Sheets.Count
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Copy before:=targetWorkBook.Sheets(1)
   Next
```

Or some such stuff, I may have the books backwards or I may be misunderstanding it. Either way you get the idea, if you know what sheet to get, just do this part in your `Select Case`.

---

#### selectBlock() As Range

What argument is this taking? Right now you use `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`. Be explicit about what you want -

```
Private Function GetCells(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet) As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    lastColumn = targetSheet.Cells(1, targetSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set GetCells = targetSheet.Range(targetSheet.Cells(2, 1), targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
End Function
```

In this case I don't think you need to break out the last row and last column functions, they are one line. However, if you're already taking the sheets you need and copying them, you have no reason for this, unless you're doing something else to them later.

---

#### Function Arguments

So I touched on it briefly - Functions should be used when something is *returned* and subs should be used when something *happens*.

You also want to take all your parameters `ByVal` instead of `ByRef`, which it's doing implicitly when you don't tell it.

Also you're using `integer`instead of `Long` - Integers - [integers are obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520). According to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164506(v=office.10).aspx) VBA *silently* converts all integers to `long`.

---

#### Handling Errors

[image]

> ```
> On Error Resume Next
> selectBlock().ClearContents
> On Error GoTo Errorhandler
> ```

So you want to plow right over any errors and then go back to error checking? Handle those errors! When you throw to an error handler, you have the `err.Number`, which you know, so just throw that at the user. And use this type of format -

```
CleanExit:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    CustomErrorHandler Err
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

What you're doing will work, but it might be better to do it this way.

---

#### Constants

One thing I notice is that you have a lot of prompt dialog. Think about taking all those into string constants at the top and using that variable instead of typing them out everywhere, it just seems clearner

Answer (score 0):

Some quick comments.

In VBA, don't use `()` for left hand calls to subroutines. i.e. use `PCB 2` instead of `PCB (2)`. Not a big issue in this case, but the `()` actually means something in VBA and pre-evaluates expressions.

You don't need to `.Activate` your windows. For starters, you already have turned `ScreenUpdating` off (for good reason). Explicitly address your ranges

```
Windows(fileName).Activate
ws.Activate
selectBlock().Copy
```

Can become

```
selectblock(fileNameWB.ws).Copy
```

Because you also get rid of ActiveSheet from `selectblock`:

```
Function selectBlock(ws as worksheet) As Range
    Dim row As Long: row = numRows() 'Finds last populated row
    Dim col As Long: col = numCols() 'Finds last populated column
    Set selectBlock = Range("A2:" & ws.Cells(row, col).Address(False, False))
   'sets this area starting from cell A2 as the Range
End Function
```

but your `selectBlock` function is really `ws.UsedRange.Offset(1,0)`. That is, everything bar the first row. This also means that you don't need the helper functions `numrows` or `numcols`.

You open multiple workbooks in your dialog, but you don't explicitly address each workbook.

Your use of `On Error` should be reconsidered. Plan for some errors and handle them in the code. Using functions like `UsedRange` will prevent some errors so you don't have to `Resume Next`. Ideally, you should not use `On Error` at all, particularly in a coding example like you have here.